# Replace class acording to variable in html file

Tags: bash, sed

I've got the following html:

```
<p>lore ipsum<p>

<pre class=".bashrc"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<pre class="example.txt"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<pre class="command"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<p>lore ipsum<p>
```

...and I'd like to change it via sed into to:

```
<p>lore ipsum<p>

<pre class="language-bash" data-label=".bashrc"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<pre class="language-bash" data-label="example.txt"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<pre class="command"><code>
foo bar
</code></pre>

<p>lore ipsum<p>
```

So my question: Every `<pre class="WHATEVER">` should be changed into `<pre class="language-bash" data-label="WHATEVER">`, depending what's inside the class name of the pre tag. The only condition: If the tag class is command (`<pre class="command">`), there should be no change.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Do you have to do this in bash? A number of programming languages allow you to do regular expressions where the replacement is a function. This allows you to use a mapping data structure to find the corresponding `language-XXX` for each class. You can do this in PHP, Python, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(class)=(.[Cc][Oo][Mm]{2}[Aa][Nn][Dd])/\1\x00\2/g; s/(class=)/\1"language-bash" data-label=/g; s/(class)\x00/\1=/g;' file.html
```

By tagging and later untagging the exception, the regular substitution can be done without complications. The binary zero hardly will appear in a HTML, so no collisions have to be expected.

Comment: Is there something open, that you don't acknowledge the answer?